# What is the role of Bottom Behavior in Bottom Sheet.

Tags: android, android-appcompat, bottom-sheet

I have seen bottom dialog can work without bottom behavior. then why it needs to be used as i have read many tutorial, its written, bottom dialog and bottom behavior are must for bottom sheet.

I am taking about model bottom sheet.
 please find the following code :

```
private void createDialog() {
    if (dismissDialog()) {
        return;
    }

    List<SampleModel> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new SampleModel(R.string.share, R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
    list.add(new SampleModel(R.string.upload, R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
    list.add(new SampleModel(R.string.copy, R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
    list.add(new SampleModel(R.string.print, R.mipmap.ic_launcher));

    SampleSheetAdapter adapter = new SampleSheetAdapter(list);
    adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new SampleSheetAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(SampleSheetAdapter.ItemHolder item, int position) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext,"clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.sheet_main, null);
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


    dialog = new BottomSheetDialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(view);
    dialog.show();
}
```

the above code is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer [here - Bottom sheets](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/bottom-sheets.html#)

Hope this may helps you.